# Is there a sneak toggle in Ghost of a Tale?

Tags: ghost-of-a-tale

In *Ghost of a Tale* I find myself holding down the sneak button all the time, which can get surprisingly sore. Is a button/shortcut to switch sneak mode on or off instead?

Controller button preferred, but keyboard/mouse shortcut ok.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/app/417290/discussions/0/1368380934247544521/) there isn't any. One of the developers says that since running decreases the stamina, a toggle button wouldn't make too much sense.